# Coin-or Linear Programming: ClpPlusMinusOneMatrix representation

Tags: c++, coin-or-cbc

I'm using [Coin-or Linear Programming](https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp) library. I want to construct a [ClpPlusMinusOneMatrix](http://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/Clp/classClpPlusMinusOneMatrix.html#ae2918ebb2e31aa4be27f15e10864eb8c).  Its constructor is:

```
ClpPlusMinusOneMatrix (int numberRows, 
                       int numberColumns, 
                       bool columnOrdered, 
                       const int *indices, 
                       const CoinBigIndex *startPositive, 
                       const CoinBigIndex *startNegative);
```

It's not exactly clear what `startPositive` and `startNegative` are.  If it's the same concept as described for another class [here](http://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/Clp/classCoinPackedMatrix.html#details), then how does the matrix differentiate +1 and -1 vales?

For example, if I want to implement 1x4 matrix: `[1 -1 1 -1]`.  How does Clp know the value of the last two elements?

```
#include <coin/ClpPlusMinusOneMatrix.hpp>

int main()
{
        int indices [4] {0, 1, 2, 3}; 
        CoinBigIndex startPositive [2] {0, 4}; 
        CoinBigIndex startNegative [2] {1, 4}; 
        ClpPlusMinusOneMatrix(1, 4, false, indices, startPositive, startNegative);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this example gives you `[[1 -1] [1 -1]]`?

Comment: I don't know what this answer gives, which is partly the question.  I'm asking how would I construct the 1x4 matrix [1, -1, 1 -1].

Comment: Linear programming has nothing to do with [tag:linear-algebra].

Comment: @EJP While i get your point, this statement is quite unfortunate in isolated form :-)

Comment: @sascha Please clarify your remark. I do not understand.

Comment: @AgrimPathak If it isn't a linear-programming question either, why is it so tagged?

Comment: @EJP I just meant, that the phrase *Linear programming has nothing to do with linear-algebra* is as wrong as it gets.

Comment: @sascha I studied them both in my mathematics degree. The connection eludes me.

Comment: @EJP No kidding? Ever implemented a LP-solver? Random simplex quote (from [here](http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-02.pdf)): ```Though the simplex algorithm has solved each of our previous examples, we have yet to show that it solves
any linear program. A formal proof requires results from linear algebra```. And some slides only talking about LA-concepts in [Interior-point solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_point_method)   [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~gondzio/talks/dundee03.pdf)

Comment: @sascha I was doing it in a mathematics unit, not a computer programming unit. We weren't taught this stuff, indeed at the time I don't think the LA-based proof existed: I seem to remember there wasn't a proof at the time. I may be out of date on this. Still unsure why the question was so tagged, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you browse the source code [here](https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp/browser/stable/1.16/Clp/src/ClpPlusMinusOneMatrix.cpp), you can deduce what `startPositve` and `startNegative` are.  First, the matrix must be constructed such that all +1 elements must precede all -1 values in a row, if row major, or column, if column major.  Then `startPositive[i]` is simply the element index of the first +1 in row `i`, if row major, or column `i` if column major.